# Native Android VS2015 cannot open source files

Tags: android, c++, intellisense, visual-studio-2015

I have just started trying out the new Visual Studio 2015 Preview with cross platform development.  I got quite some parts running, until I compiled a native lib in it.
Files from the External Dependencies in the NativeActivity are giving errors as "cannot open source file "name" ", with these names being vector, set, stdexcept and others.
Properties of this 'project' are : 
[image]

while the properties of the lib are : 
[image]

I think I am missing somethings there but not sure what to do with it.

Answer (score 2):

I found that the best place to add library dependencies is under Configuration Properites -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies. Use one line per library and the macro `$(SolutionDir)` is your friend. `$(SolutionDir)` is the location of your .sln file.

Comment: This helped me out A lot! Expect that one file remains which cant find 'vector' although it's in the same project with other files which seem to find it. (#include <vector>) Chances are this is the first file to call it.

Comment: You may have a syntax error of some sort. It would be very strange for one file in a project to find `<vector>` and another file to not find it. However it is more likely that you need to turn on STL support and `<vector>` is not available to any file. Turn on STL with Configuration Properties -> General -> Use of STL. Good options are `LLVM libc++ static library` (fewer features, more compatible with CLANG) and `GNU STL static library` (more features, I had an issue that required me to turn off the CLANG optimizer to prevent a segfault).